# Eliminar todos los elementos con el mismo dominio en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente `array:`

```
array = [

'javi@indaloymedia.com',
'caroline@grupoplatinum.com'

]
```

Luego tengo el siguiente fichero:

```
javi@indaloymedia.com
asdsd@indaloymedia.com
jasdasd@indaloymedia.com
caroline@grupoplatinum.com
asdasde@grupoplatinum.com
wata@man.com
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que se eliminen todos los elementos que esten en el array con dominio ***indaloymedia.com*** es decir para que el fichero quede de la siguiente manera:

```
wata@man.com
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué has intentado? Veo que tus últimas preguntas tratan cosas bastante parecidas, por lo que seguro que tienes código con el que empezar la tarea.

Comment: he intenetado poniendo en el array una expresion regular tipo '*@indaloymedia.com' pero nada he iterando con un for tampoco

Comment: dale pues a [edit] y añade lo que intentaste. Más que nada que eres un usuario lo suficientemente antiguo aquí como para saber que hay que indicar estas cosas :) Además, es bueno indicar si el problema está en la gestión del fichero o bien en la detección de elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez hayas obtenido la lista de dominios a excluir, cosa que sale de tu lista de correos quedándose con lo que tengan tras la arroba, basta iterar por cada línea del fichero de entrada y verificar si el dominio en esa línea está en la lista de dominios a excluir. Si no está, la copias al fichero de salida.

Es decir:

```
def get_dominio(email):
   # Esta función retorna la parte dominio de un email
   return email.split("@")[-1].strip()  # strip elimina posibles espacios o retornos de carro al final

# Obtener lista de dominios a excluir
excluidos = [ get_dominio(email) for email in array ]

# Abrir el fichero de entrada y otro de salida
with open("entrada.txt") as f_in, open("salida.txt") as f_out:
   # Iterar por el fichero de entrada
   for linea in f_in:
        if get_dominio(linea) not in excluidos:
            f_out.write(linea)
```

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Gracias por la corrección! Efectivamente era `email` en vez de `x`. Lo he sacado a una función para poder reusarlo, al principio sobre la lista de emails que tiene en `array` y después para cada línea del fichero de entrada (de ahí el `.strip()`).

Answer (score 2):

Ahora con la edición que has hecho creo que ya entiendo lo que quieres, mira a ver si es esto:

```
dominios = [x.split('@')[1] for x in array]

with open('archivo.txt', 'r') as f:
    emails = [linea for linea in f.readlines() if all(map(lambda x:x not in linea, dominios))]

with open('archivoNuevo.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write(linea) for linea in emails]
```

Comment: eso no es lo que busco ya que tiene que iterar todo el array en busca de eliminar los dominios que aparecen en el array no uno solo como pones tu

Comment: es que en el array tienes también '@grupoplatinum.com' y no lo has eliminado en el ejemplo, por eso no quedaba muy claro

Comment: lo corrijo gracias

Comment: También he editado la respuesta y creo que ya hace lo que pedías

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace  Aunque mi solución es muy similar a la tuya, creo que es más eficiente al mirar si el dominio extraido de la linea del fichero está en la lista `excluidos`, pues eso se hace con un `not in`, implementado internamente en C por Python, mientras que tu solución requiere iterar por la lista de excluidos, comparar con cada uno, y hacer un `all()`  para ver que no es ninguno de ellos, y eso para cada linea de entrada. Además, el uso de comprensiones de listas, map, lambdas... lo hace más difícil de leer para un principiante. Aún así, +1 por resolver el problema.

Comment: Perfecto, todas esas cosas no las sé por eso lo ponía, para saber por qué, no para sonar borde (si es que ha sonado así, por eso he borrado el comentario, que ya no aportaba nada)

Comment: @AdriánSanzWallace Otro detalle, las comprensiones de listas deben usarse para _crear_ listas. En ese sentido las dos primeras que has puesto son correctas, pues son usadas para crear respectivamente la lista de dominios a excluir y la lista con resultados a volcar a disco. Pero la tercera comprensión no la usas para _crear_ una lista (aunque se crea una, con los valores retornados por cada `f.write()`), sino por sus _efectos colaterales_, que consisten en la escritura en disco. Esto es un antipatrón. Mejor sería usar un bucle normal o `f.write("".join(emails))`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por el consejo!!